# Setting up drupal with docker using two containers? nginx and mariadb

Tags: drupal, nginx, docker, mariadb

I am trying to get a Drupal local development environment up and running using docker.

The site I am working on is live, running on a digital ocean server. When I access that server (ssh -p 1111 @234.234.234.23)
and run (docker ps) I can see two containers running. One is for the nginx-php5-drupal container that I got from here (https://github.com/bnchdrff/dockerfiles)

The other container is a mariadb container that holds the database for the drupal site.

I have run (docker export) on both of these containers, downloaded them and then set them up as images locally, named (mariadb:local) and (bnchdrff/nginx-php5-drupal:latest) respectively

I then run:

sudo docker run -d --name mariadb mariadb:local /sbin/init

sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 2222:22 --name nginx-php5-drupal-bnchdrff --link mariadb:db bnchdrff/nginx-php5-drupal:latest   /sbin/init

I then attempt to navigate to localhost:80 and/or localhost in my browser...

Nothing appears.

Am I doing this right?

My understanding is patchy as I am new to all of this. I think the best thing for me to do is to restart the whole process from exporting the running containers from the live site to running them locally because I  swapped out the live nginx-php5-drupal container for the old one from the github repo and I think the person who put the site online customised it...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a MAC OS you'll need to use the boot2docker ip address. 
You can get this by running the following command: boot2docker ip

https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/